# I want to invoke my iOS app unit tests from another sample iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest, xctestcase

I have a list of unit tests for my iOS app which are running in the Jenkins build.

**My Requirement** - I want to invoke these unit tests from a sample iOS app. The sample iOS app will have a button 'Test', once it clicked, It has to run all the unit tests within that sample app.

Is this possible? if yes, can you give me some suggestions.

**note:-** App is developed using Objective-C

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hem - so you have your regular app and you want to test it by another app which will trigger Jenkins unit tests job (sry, I am working with Gitlab, so I am not sure if Jenkins has jobs or something different). 
It would be possible, just really complicated - on which branch/commit would it trigger your tests? On last commit? Checkout Github+Jenkins webhooks - https://dzone.com/articles/adding-a-github-webhook-in-your-jenkins-pipeline, that might work.

Comment: What's the motivating reason behind this requirement?